# Adding a Wizard to My Plugin

Tags: plugins

I am interested in developing a Wordpress plugin.  I've noticed that, after activating other Wordpress plugins, they'll display a "You're almost done, just run the wizard" message at the top of every admin page. (See screenshot for one example of this)

[image]

If there officially support for this some Wordpress api and/or system?  Or is this something crafy the developers of this plugin have done? (The plugin is WooCommerce -- mentioned only in case the specific plugin matters, this is not an (off topic) WooCommerce question)

Regardless of the answer to the above, how can I achieve this effect in my own plugins?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's WordPress API and the proper tool to use for this is [`register_activation_hook`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_activation_hook/) which fires right after your plugin activation, or [`after_setup_theme`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_setup_theme) if you were doing this work for a theme.

Here's an example use, the code should be placed in the main plugin loader file, or if in a sub-directory then provide a path to `__FILE__` property from the main file:

```
add_action( "admin_init", function(){
    if ( get_option( $opt_name = "se_show_my_plugin_wizard_notice" ) ) {
        delete_option( $opt_name );
        add_action( "admin_notices", "se_wizard_notice" );
    } return;
});

/**
  * Check if user has completed wizard already
  * if so then return true (don't show notice)
  *
  */
function se_wizard_completed() {
    return false;
}

function se_wizard_notice() {

    if ( se_wizard_completed() ) return; // completed already
    ?>

    <div class="updated notice is-dismissible">
        <p>Welcome to my plugin! You're almost there, but we think this wizard might help you setup the plugin.</p>
        <p><a href="admin.php?page=my_plugin_wizard" class="button button-primary">Run wizard</a> <a href="javascript:window.location.reload()" class="button">dismiss</a></p>
    </div>

    <?php

}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, function() {
    update_option( "se_show_my_plugin_wizard_notice", 1 );
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: How to add the page my_plugin_wizard with Wordpress? I mean how to add a page to Wordpress admin