# How can I redirect to my custom page without loading the Dashboard itself?

Tags: pages, wp-redirect

I'm creating a page using:

```
/**
 * Add the admin menu item, under Appearance.
 */
public function addAdminMenu() {
    $page = add_theme_page(
        esc_html__( 'Setup' ),
        esc_html__( 'Setup' ),
        'manage_options', 'setup_page',
        [ $this, 'setupPageContent' ]
    );

    add_action( 'load-' . $page, [$this, 'localizeSetupScreenJS'] );
    add_action( 'load-' . $page, [$this, 'enqueueSetupScreenCSS'] );
}
```

The function `addAdminMenu` is called:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', [$this, 'addAdminMenu' ]);
```

Which adds a nice entry under "Appearance" for my page. As such, my page's link is:

```
http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-admin/themes.php?page=setup_page
```

I saw some plugins, WooCommerce especially, after they've been activated, they re-direct / ask you to go to a page where you can tell they're still in the back-end, but the side menu or any other menus besides their content doesn't show.

I'm looking for a hook like `before_output_wordpress_dashboard`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `register_activation_hook()`

More info [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/activation-deactivation-hooks/).

And [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/232305/adding-a-wizard-to-my-plugin).

Greetz, Bjorn